# Alternative to REGEXP_LIKE in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Can you please tell me if there is any alternative function which I can use for REGEXP_LIKE ?

I have the following situation:

```
Names:
ID NAME
1  Alex
2  Jim
3  Tom

Invoices:
ID Amount Name_IDs
1  100    1;2;
2  200    2;3;

Wanted output:
Invoice_ID Names     Amount:
1          Alex;Jim; 100
2          Jim;Tom;  200
```

I know that the database model is not quite technically right, but now I'm using a query for this with REGEXP_LIKE to add in a listagg() the names, but the performance is very very slow.

```
SELECT inv.id as invoice_id, 
       SELECT listagg(n.name,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) from names where REGEXP_LIKE(inv.names, '(^|\W)' || n.name || '(\W|$) 'as names
       inv.amount as amount
from invoices inv;
```

Can you please give me any idea how to improve this query ?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want performance, store the data in a SQLish way -- an `InvoiceNames` table with one row per invoice and per name.

Comment: And even if I can do this, how can I store all the names into one column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an index on your `names` table then this should be faster:

```
select i.id,
       i.amount,
       (select listagg(n.name, ';') within group(order by null)
          from (select trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, level)) ASPLIT
                  from (select i.name_ids as str from dual)
                connect by regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, level) is not null) t
          join names n
            on n.id = t.asplit)
  from invoices i;
```

i.e. first split by `Name_IDs` and join with the `names` table.

Comment: Very useful! Thank you! It helps!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you change your data model to something like the following:

```
NAMES:
ID_NAMES NAME
10       Alex
20       Jim
30       Tom

INVOICES:
ID_INVOICE Amount
1          100
2          200

INVOICE_NAMES:
ID_INVOICE  ID_NAME
1           10
1           20
2           20
2           30
```

Best of luck.